# Stellar Payments: Routing Algorithm

Tags: payments

Where can I get information on the routing algorithm employed in Stellar ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're thinking about the path finding, used for doing cross-asset payments, there was a recent update to it, described  here:

https://github.com/stellar/go/pull/719